# What did Trinity mean by this line in The Matrix Reloaded?

Tags: the-matrix, language-explanation

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), Neo saves Trinity's life after she's shot by an Agent while falling from a building. She then says:

> **I guess this makes us even**.

What did she mean by that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's almost certainly a callback to the climax of the first film, in which Neo's heart flatlined after he was shot by Agent Smith within the Matrix, and Trinity revived him with a softly-spoken speech and a kiss. At this point, you could say that he owed her a debt (his life), so they weren't even.

> <sub>*The Matrix* (1999)</sub>

In *Reloaded*, Trinity's heart flatlined after she was shot by an Agent within the Matrix, and Neo revived her by massaging her virtual heart with his virtual hand. At this point, you could say that he repaid the debt he owed her from the previous film, so they were now even.

> <sub>*The Matrix Reloaded* (2003)</sub>

See also the idiom, to ['be even (with someone).'](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+even)

> be even (with someone)
>
> 1. To not be indebted (to someone) for something; to not owe (someone) anything.